# 3 points on a graph

Tags: graphing-functions

3 distinct points are on the graph $y=4x^2$ The x coordinates form an arithmetic sequence while the y coordinates form a geometric sequence, what are the possible values of the common ratio?

Naming the points :
$(A,4A^2), (B, 4B^2), (C, 4C^2)$

X = common difference
r = common ratio

Equations: 
$A+x = B; B+x =C$

$A^2(r) = B^2; B^2(r)=C^2$

Solving for x

$A^2(r) = (A+x)^2$

I get
$x=(-A\pm A\sqrt{r})/2$

then
$B^2(r) = C^2$

$A^2(r^2)=(A+2x)^2$

$A^2(r^2)=(A-A\pm A\sqrt{r})^2$

which results in $r=1$ or $r=0$

Where did i go wrong?

Comment: $A^2(r) = (A+x)^2 \Rightarrow x=-A\pm A\sqrt{r}$

Answer (score 1):

$x=(-2A\pm 2A\sqrt r)/2=-A\pm A\sqrt r$, not $x=(-A\pm A\sqrt r)/2$.

Continuing from $A^2(r^2)=(A+2x)^2$,

$$A^2(r^2)=(A-2A\pm 2A\sqrt r)^2\\
A^2(r^2)=(-A\pm 2A\sqrt r)^2\\
A^2(r^2)=A^2+4A^2r\pm4A^2\sqrt r\\
r^2=1+4r\pm4\sqrt r\\
r^2-4r-1=\pm\sqrt{16r}\text.$$

Squaring both sides,
$$r^4+16r^2+1-8r^3-2r^2+8r=16r\\
r^4-8r^3+14r^2-8r+1=0\\
(r-1)^2(r^2-6r+1)=0\\
r=1\lor r=3\pm2\sqrt2\text.$$

Consider that $A,B,C$ are distinct, so $r\ne1$. Therefore,
$$r=3\pm2\sqrt2\text.$$

Comment: Of which $\,r=1\,$ is not eligible, since the three points are supposedly distinct.

Comment: @dxiv Where in the question it says so?

Comment: You are right, it nowhere literally says so. But I thought that was what `3 points` was supposed to mean in the context, so I took it as an implicit assumption. Otherwise, for example, one could choose all three points to be $\,(0,0)\,$ and then the answer would be "*any common ratio will work*".

Comment: sorry i forgot to include that part, it does say distinct points

Comment: @SuperMage1 Would you mind editing it into the question?

Answer (score 1):

Let the abscissae of the three points be $a,b,c$, then the conditions for AP and GP are:

$$
\begin{align}
a+c &= 2b \tag{1} \\
(4a^2)\cdot(4c^2) &= (4b^2)^2 \tag{2}
\end{align}
$$

Substituting $(1)$ into $(2)$ gives:

$$
\begin{align}
16a^2c^2 = (a+c)^4 \;\;&\iff\;\; (a+c)^4 - 16a^2c^2 = 0 \\
 &\iff\;\; \big((a+c)^2-4ac\big)\big((a+c)^2+4ac)=0 \\
 &\iff\;\; (a-c)^2(a^2+6ac+c^2) = 0
\end{align}
$$

The first factor cannot be $0$ since $a,b,c$ are distinct, which leaves $\,a^2+6ac+c^2=0\,$.

None of $a,b,c$ can be $0\,$, since the GP condition would imply that the other two are $0$ as well, and a quadratic cannot have three distinct roots. Then dividing by $a^2\ne0$ gives $\,\left(\dfrac{c}{a}\right)^2+6\left(\dfrac{c}{a}\right)+1=0\,$ with the roots $\dfrac{c}{a}=-3 \pm 2 \sqrt{2}\,$, and so the common ratio of the GP is $\,\pm\sqrt{\dfrac{4c^2}{4a^2}} = \pm(3 \pm 2 \sqrt{2})\,$. It still remains to be verified whether actual $\,a,b,c\,$ solutions do in fact exist in each of the four cases.

---

[ *EDIT* ] The common ratio of the GP must be positive since all $y$ coordinates are positive, as noted by @user_194421. This eliminates the negative solutions, and leaves only $\,3 \pm 2\sqrt{2}\,$ to be checked.

Comment: If the common ratio is negative, at least one of $4A^2,4B^2,4C^2$ would be negative or $0$.

Comment: @user_194421 Good point, thank you. Added the note to the answer.